# howto change color on jqPlot datapoint labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

I have a graph generated by `jqPlot`.
Data Point Labels are used the show additional information on the graph, like in this example: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/point-labels.php

As you can see, the color of the data point labels is always black.
But I would like to change the color of the data point labels to the same color as the graph is (by the way: I don't talk about the legend or the tick-label).

Searching trough the options page (http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html) I found no option to change this color.

So the question is: **Is there a (other) way to change the color of the data point labels?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that with CSS. By targeting the class `.jqplot-point-label`. See the [example](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/point-labels.php#chart3) provided on the page

Comment: oh, i read on that part at the example page.. but yes - that's not to answer, but it points me to the right answer: Every series has his own class (which is not explained in the example). Now i changed the color by reverence an DOM element with this class: `$('.jqplot-series-'+i).css('color','#123456');` where `i` is the number of the series you like to modify. thank you

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the `.jqplot-series-$i` class, reading the source reveals that the `.jqplot-data-label` class is also applied to these label items.

Comment: +1 because the pie charts use `.jqplot-data-label` and not `.jqplot-point-label`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without CSS.

for series set

```
pointLabels:{ 
  show:true,
  escapeHTML:false
}
```

and

```
var label = '<span style="color:red">MyLabel</span>';
var seriesData = [[1,2,label], [3,4,label]];
```

Of course you can add a span in JavaScript loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a donut chat and this is how i changed the target and label color

```
.jqplot-target{
     color: #ffffff !important ;

 }
.jqplot-table-legend{
    color: #666666 !important ;

}
```